# How can I ask gradle for the value of a property from the command line?

Tags: gradle

For example, if I wanted a shell script to be able to get the value of `rootProject.name`, how could I do this? Ideally, I'd like to invoke `./gradlew` with some set of arguments and have it print the property value (and nothing else) to stdout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get gradle property from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581105/how-to-get-gradle-property-from-command-line)

Comment: It's counter-intuitive that Gradle doesn't support this. Afterall, it's just an object with values set on its members (if my understanding is correct).

Comment: It's strange that you can't do `gradle :allprojects` the when you can do `gradle :properties`

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, here is my Gradle wrapper version:

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.4 x86_64
```

This is an existing task to give you an idea of the properties available:

```
$ ./gradlew properties


> Task :properties

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

allprojects: [root project 'myProject', project ':otherProject', ...]
...
rootDir: /path/to/rootDir
rootProject: root project 'myProject'
...
version: 2.3.0
...
```

Here is a custom task I've built to print out a project property

```
class ResolveProperties extends DefaultTask {

  @Input
  String prop

  ResolveProperties() {
    // if no --prop=<property> is provided, default to spitting out all properties
    prop = "properties"
  }

  @Option(option = 'prop', description = 'Set the property to be evaluated for the project.')
  void setProp(final String prop) {
    this.prop = prop
  }

  @TaskAction
  void resolveProp() {
    List<String> propPath = this.prop.tokenize('.')
    int n = propPath.size()
    def currentProp = project
    propPath.eachWithIndex { p, i ->
        if(currentProp.hasProperty(p)) {
          currentProp = currentProp.property(p)
        }
        else {
          throw new GradleException("failed to resolve property: ${this.prop}")
        }
    }
    println "${this.prop} -> ${currentProp}"
  }
}

task resolveProperties(type: ResolveProperties)
```

And this is how I use my custom task with a `--prop` parameter (indicated by `@Option(option = 'prop'`. I'm using the `-q` (quiet) Gradle option to suppress some of the extra output.

```
$ ./gradlew -q resolveProperties --prop=rootProject.name
rootProject.name -> onestop
resolveProperties took 0 seconds
$ ./gradlew -q resolveProperties --prop=rootProject.version
rootProject.version -> 2.3.0
resolveProperties took 0 seconds
$ ./gradlew -q resolveProperties --prop=rootProject.group
rootProject.group -> org.cedar.onestop
resolveProperties took 0 seconds
```

Because we are throwing a `GradleException` when we can't find the property, in Bash you can check the return code of the command to know when to parse out the value. The formatting of a successful output is up to you and you could make it easily parsed.

```
$ ./gradlew -q resolveProperties --prop=does.not.exist
resolveProperties took 0 seconds

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/elliott/Documents/GitHub/onestop/build.gradle' line: 259

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':resolveProperties'.
> failed to resolve property: does.not.exist

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

In case of a failure like the one above, we get a non-zero return code in Bash, and we know we don't need to try and parse out the value:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a simple way in Gradle to *only* give the value you are concerned with to `stdout` (prevent some parsing), but this gets you most of the way there with some flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

If it is still relevant ...

### Possible Solution A: print value of "*rootProject.name*" on cmd line

Add task in build.gradle:

```js
/**
 * Prints value of property "rootProject.name" to stdout.
 *
 * Usage: ./gradlew -q printRootProjectName
 */
task printRootProjectName {
  doLast {
    println(project.findProperty('rootProject').name)
  }
}
```

### Possible Solution B: print a property value as provided on cmd line

Add task in build.gradle:

```js
/**
 * Print value of property provided in "-Pprop" on command line to stdout.
 *
 * Usage Example: ./gradlew -q printProperty -Pprop=rootProject.name
 */
task printProperty {
  doLast {
    // get the "property name" in question from commandline:
    String prop = project.findProperty('prop')
    if (prop == null) {
      return // or use println ...
    }

    // treat as property name:
    Object theProperty = project.findProperty(prop)

    if (null == theProperty) {
      // try to handle provided information as "nested property"
      List < String > thePropPath = prop.split('\\.').toList()

      theProperty = project.findProperty(thePropPath.head())

      // aux. closure to travel "property path"
      def pp = {
        s,
        t - >
        if (s != null && s.hasProperty(t).is(true)) {
          return s.property(t)
        }
        return null
      }
      thePropPath.tail().each {
        item - >
          theProperty = pp(theProperty, item)
      }
    }
    println(theProperty ? : "") // or print "null" ...
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately your solution A doesn't work. Try this file:
`plugins {
    id 'java'
}

task printRootProjectName {
  doLast {
    println(project.findProperty('rootProject').name)
  }
}

build {
    println 'hi'
}`