# How to get gradle property from command line?

Tags: gradle

I am trying read a project property from command line interface. There is a task `gradle properties`, which prints all of them. Therefore, I can write: `gradle properties | grep "rootProject: root project" | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d "'"` and get what I want. The returned result is correct. I would like to use a proper gradle command to achieve the same result. What is a gradle command to get the project name?

this is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

tasks.register("rootProjectName") {
    doLast {
        println(rootProject.name)
    }
}

build {
    println 'hi'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210735/how-can-i-ask-gradle-for-the-value-of-a-property-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're just after the `rootProject.name` property. There is no built-in Gradle [**task**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:projects_and_tasks) that will give you that property. You can write a simple task that prints that value to the console which will simplify your command.

```
tasks.register("rootProjectName") {
    doLast {
        println(rootProject.name)
    }
}
```

Then simply call that task with [`-q`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#setting_log_level):

```
$ ./gradlew rootProjectName -q
demo
```

You can see `demo` is simply printed out for this example.

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work. It prints all outputs of all gradle tasks that have println statement. In my case it prints thee lines

Comment: simply add the following code to see it:  
  
```build {println 'hi' }```

Comment: Please update the question to include your project layout and Gradle files.

Comment: I added my the content of `build.gradle` into the question

Answer (score 0):

So far the closest I got is the following `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

task printRootProjectName {
    doLast {
      println('root project: ' + rootProject.name)
    }
}

build {
    println 'unwanted output'
}
```

and then:

```
gradle printRootProjectName -q | grep "root project:" | awk '{print $NF}' | head -n 1
```